# IF statement Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013.

I'm making a Universal application for Windows Phone 8.1.

On the MainPage I have three CheckBoxes, when some of these CheckBoxes are checked, then the TextBlock is counting Value. After the value become grater or equal then 22, some images should become invisible. If the value is less then 22 all images should be visible.

This is some examples which I tried, but I was unlucky.

```
    private void points_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (points.Text == "22")
        {
            hole10img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility;()
        }
    }
```

also I tried:

```
    private void points_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (points.Text == "22")
        {
                hole10img.Visibility = false;
        }
    }
```

but then I got the error:

> cannot implicitly convert type bool' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility'

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility probably isn't a bool then; it's probably an object.

Comment: `hole10img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility;()` this will not compile.

Comment: Describe "but I was unlucky".

Comment: I with that mean: Way how i try fix my problem doesn't work...

Comment: Describe "doesn't work". We can't look at your screen.

Answer (score 6):

`Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility` is an Enum. You need another dot and specification:

```
hole10img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

For example..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int n = 0;
bool b = int.TryParse(points.Text, out n);

if (b && n >= 22)
{
     hole10img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be 'b', not the 'res'.

Comment: Code  looks great, but for what object have to put this code?
For Page_loaded?

Comment: I don't know. Just replace your code in `points_Loaded` with this.

Comment: Do you have a method that fires when  text in textblock changes? You can do this in that method.

Comment: ohh sorry but no..
I'm new one there in WP Apps...
Can you lease tell me more about this method?

Comment: I can not debug the air. Please ask another question and provide some code. There will be something like textchanged event. Add a handler to that event and place the code inside.

Comment: Can you watch this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834351/method-windows-phone-8-1

Answer (score 0):

Update all your CheckBox_Checked_XX methods like this one:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked_17(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SetText((Convert.ToInt32(points.Text) + 5));
        }
```

And create a new method:

```
    private void SetText(int value)
    {
        this.points.Text = value.ToString();
        if (value >= 22)
        {
            hole10img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole11img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole12img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole13img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole14img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole15img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole16img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole17img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            hole18img.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

And I strongly recommend you to read a book about C#. It will be much easier.